# How to use css to change svg color when it's embbed in img tag?(Vue3)

Tags: css, svg

I got this problem when I'm practice to create a tabBar in a VueCLI3 project.

At first I just want to make an repeatitive svg file to place active color but I think it's not good if it can't change color dynamically.

I try to solve problem by myself but I'm still confused after spend a lot of time searching.

Here is my part of code:

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <tab-bar>
      <tab-bar-item>
        <template #item-pic>
          <img src="./assets/img/tabBar/ic_home.svg"  />
        </template>
        <template #item-pic-active>
          <img src="./assets/img/tabBar/ic_home-active.svg"  />
        </template>
        <template #item-text>
          <div class="text">home page</div>
        </template>
      </tab-bar-item>
      ...
    </tab-bar>
  </div>
</template>
```

ic_home.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg class="icon" width="200px" height="200.00px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="#333333" d="M948.543896 348.800031L536.116641 64.368028a42.460804 42.460804 0 0 0-48.465221 0L75.226165 348.800031A42.653753 42.653753 0 0 0 56.794025 383.898777v426.649504c0 86.297246 70.140506 156.437752 156.436752 156.437752h597.306507c86.295246 0 156.436752-70.140506 156.436752-156.437752V383.898777a42.656753 42.656753 0 0 0-18.43014-35.098746zM426.497545 881.597548V725.160795a71.170234 71.170234 0 0 1 71.107251-71.103252h28.4445a71.207225 71.207225 0 0 1 71.10825 71.107251V881.597548z m455.14799-71.051266a71.170234 71.170234 0 0 1-71.107251 71.10825H682.486048V725.160795c0-86.240261-70.140506-156.437752-156.436752-156.437751h-28.4445c-86.295246 0-156.436752 70.197491-156.436752 156.437751v156.494737H213.230777a71.134244 71.134244 0 0 1-71.107251-71.108251V406.312867L511.88503 151.290109l369.760505 255.022758z" />
</svg>
```

TabBar.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="tab-bar">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>
    #tab-bar{
        display: flex;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 -3px 1px darkgrey;
    }
</style>
```

TabItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="tab-bar-item" v-bind:class="{'is-active':isActive}">
    <slot v-if="!isActive" name="item-pic"></slot>
    <slot v-else name="item-pic-active"></slot>
    <slot name="item-text"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            // isActive:true
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style>
.tab-bar-item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.is-active{
    color: red;
    fill: currentColor;
    
}

</style>
```

Where is the rope?

Comment: CSS doesn't touch anything inside an IMG. You have to load the SVG and inject it in the DOM. Like this blog does: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd